# Можно ли при редиректе в строке браузера показывать другую страницу?

Tags: php

Например есть страница 1.html, которая перенаправляет посетителя на страницу 2.html. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при перенаправлении на страницу 2.html в строке браузера был адрес страницы 1.html?

Comment: почитай про фреймы

Comment: Нет. Фреймы не подходят. Нужно, чтобы не внутри страницы открывалась страницы, а именно новая страница.

Comment: Тогда это ,скорее всего, не возможно.

Comment: можешь создавать сессию при клике, проверять если есть сессия то 

    include_once '/2.php';

адрес будет тот который и остался, но содержание страницы будет другое

Comment: А как сессию создать? Я новичёк :)

Comment: Дело в том, что клика никакого нет. Просто в строке браузера вводят один адрес, а должена отображаться другая страница.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, средствами веб-сервера.

Из вопроса неясен сценарий. Пользователь должен видеть что-то от `page1.html`, или та просто перебрасывает его на `page2.html`?

Куда копать: [Apache mod_rewrite](http://www.egoroff.spb.ru/portfolio/apache/mod_rewrite.html), [nginx http_rewrite_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html). Эти штуки позволяют на запрос `www.site.ru/page1.html` выдавать на самом деле `page2.html`, например.

Comment: Если честно, то мне это ни о чём не сказало.

Comment: @Pavlik290592, сожалеем.